# indexing expressions in sql

Tags: sql, indexing

I have a database where one of the common queries is has a "where blobCol is null", I think that this is getting bad performance (as in a full table scan). I have no need to index the contents of the blobCol.

What indexes would improve this? Can an index be built on an expression (blobCol is not null) rather than just a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, most DBMSs support it, for instance in [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createindex.html) it is

```
CREATE INDEX notNullblob ON myTable (blobCol is not NULL);
```

It seems that the best you could do on SQL Server though is to create a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx) that, for example, will contain 1 if blob is null and 0 otherwise and create an index over that.

Comment: Not sure, but I think that it doesn't

Comment: it would seem that MySQL does not support this. OTOH an index with a prefix length of 1 does very well.

Answer (score 1):

Some databases allow indexes on expressions but a plain index should reduce the running time of your query significantly.

Comment: My concern is that a plain old index will use up a lot of resources indexing the data when all I want is if there is any data at all.

Comment: That's a fair point and, as I mentioned, some databases support indexes on expressions but I didn't know if yours was one of them as you didn't specify the database you were using.